# Random forests in low-dimensional vs high-dimensional datasets

Tags: random-forest, feature-selection, high-dimensional

**Summary: Is random forest naturally more robust to bad features in high vs low dimensional datasets?**

I've made a number of text classifiers with Scikit's Random Forest, with thousands of features from text tokenization, and have been happy with them. They're easy to work with, even with mostly out-of-the-box hyperparameters, and I get to decent classification performance relatively quickly. Dimensionality reduction like T-SVD has never helped these for me

I've **assumed** this means RF is talented at feature selection and ignoring features that don't aid prediction.

Now I'm working on a much lower-dimensional problem (2-50 features, N=2000 samples), and I've been surprised that RF is **very sensitive to adding bad features**.

- Very often adding one feature decreases the classification performance (AUC from CV).
- I've tried some hyperparameter tuning, but not sure how to optimize its "robustness to trying bad features".
- It's much harder to try features than in past experiences...more manual trial and error, even single levels of categorical variables at a time.

I know RFs were "designed" for high-dimensional situations. But I assumed they would be relatively robust to trying noise features -- which is why you can throw a lot of text tokens at it. I figured even in low-dimensional situations, with RF I could throw 100 ideas at it and it would sift through em. (Then after I could find a parsimonious set of features that's carrying the weight.) I seem to be wrong.

Would love to improve my intuition here.

**Is my experience (adding bad features degrades RF performance more in my lower-dimensional problem than higher-dimensional ones) because of...**

1. A known behavior of RF, being easier to work with when there are very high dimensions?
2. I've got improper hyperparameters in my lower-dimensional situation, not adding enough "randomness" to the forest like you get in higher-dimensional situations?
3. Not a universal experience, but related to unique characteristics of datasets, sample size, etc?
4. Something else?

Thank you so much for any guidance!